# Make wrapper take all viewport after header

Tags: html, css

so basically I want have the following structure: HEADER - fixed width, div.wrapper - take all remaining viewport after header (e.g. if header is 100px height, and my total viewport's height is 900px I want the .wrapper's height to be 800px). And then I have a footer with no fixed height which must come immeditately after .wrapper.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <footer>
    <P>FOOTER</P><P>FOOTER</P><P>FOOTER</P><P>FOOTER</P>
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {min-height:100%; width:100%;}

header {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height:100%;
}

footer {
  background-color:green;  

}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/xwckn1kn/3/

`.wrapper {height:100%}` not working.

Answer (score 2):

Since the footer is supposed to be below the viewport initially, we can use `calc` as the header is a known height

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: blue;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>

  <footer>
    <P>FOOTER</P>
    <P>FOOTER</P>
    <P>FOOTER</P>
    <P>FOOTER</P>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I do not need the footer to be seen, it can only be shown with scroll.

Comment: Update the asnwer.